# Maven plugin builds but can't execute due to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, slf4j, pom.xml

I am using the maven-jspc-plugin in my pom.xml.

When i try to execute the jsp-compile goal (which executes the plugin) I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory 
at org.apache.juli.logging.Slf4jLog.<init>(Slf4jLog.java:29) 
at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:54)    
at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:35) 
at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.OriginalTldLocationsCache.<init>(OriginalTldLocationsCache.java:81) 
at org.apache.sling.maven.jspc.JspcMojo.initServletContext(JspcMojo.java:426)
```

I've tried downloading the (open) source for the maven-jspc-plugin and i am able to easily "mvn install" -- I don't get any build issues, however when i use that build in my project pom it still crashes and tells me it can't find LoggerFactory.

I've logged an issue with the Apache Sling project but am not making much headway.
  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-2350
This link includes some more troubleshooting info as well as a simple maven project that uses the maven plugin. downloading the jspc-test.zip and "mvn install"ing will result in the error I've mentioned.

Also, i took a peak at the org.apache.juli pom.xml and it doesnt appear to list any dependencies at all.

Any thoughts on how to resolve would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try adding the SLF4J api dependency in your POM?

Comment: yes - i tried org.slf4j.api (multiple versions), org.slf4j.simple, and quite a few other org.slf4j.slf4jlog13 and a handful of others (LoggerFactory is in org.slf4j.api so i assume thats all i need). I also tried adding the slf4j api depdency in the maven-jspc-plugin POM when building locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugin dependencies are supplied in a different part of the POM:

```
<project>
    <dependencies>
         <!-- dependencies defined here don't get included for plugins -->
    ... 
    </dependencies>
    <build>
         <plugins>
              <plugin>
                .... jspc plugin section ....
                 <dependencies>
                      <dependency>  
                      <!-- Try adding slf4j here --->
```

Though it does sounds like their POM is invalid if it doesn't already specify slf4j.

Comment: Link to the juli pom.xml (from apache's repo): https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases/org/apache/tomcat/juli/6.0.35/juli-6.0.35.pom

Comment: This worked. I am getting a warning about log4j not being initialized now and then a NullPointer exception, but i think those are different issues.