# How to precompile JSP files in Wildfly 10?

Tags: jsp, wildfly, wildfly-10

In older versions of JBoss AS, the Tomcat jasper JSPC compiler could be used to precompile JSP pages to ensure that they were all syntactically valid JSP files.

According to https://access.redhat.com/solutions/175893, as of JB EAP 6, the JSPC compiler is no longer supported.

How am I supposed to validate that JSP files are syntactically correct during a build/package process?  If not, it seems that the only solution is to launch a full JB instance during the test phase and navigate to every JSP individually to ensure that it compiles properly each time.

Is there not a WildFly supported mechanism to validate JSP pages during the build phase?

Comment: If you want to validate a multiple jsp pages then you can use Arquillian to write a test that access all jsp in a war.

Answer (score 0):

Although you are asking about Wildfly the problem is not Wildfly-related. Just try to precompile your JSPs before deployment time. You may find questions like [compile jsp using maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23211906/compile-jsp-using-maven)